# How to delete a row from DataGrid control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I know that I should use PreviewKeyDown event in order to delete a row in DataGrid so I have this code in the UI:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgPlaces"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Places}"
            PreviewKeyDown="dgPlaces_PreviewKeyDown"
    />
```

Then I have this code in the code-behind:

```
private void dgPlaces_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        if (dgPlaces.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var row in dgPlaces.SelectedItems)
            {
                //here should be delete logic for each row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code in the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel //: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {

    }

    private ObservableCollection<Place> places = new ObservableCollection<Place>()
    {
        new Place { Id = 1, City = "New York", Country = "US" },
        new Place { Id = 2, City = "Chicago", Country = "US" },
        new Place { Id = 3, City = "Miami", Country = "US" }
    };

    public ObservableCollection<Place> Places
    {
        get
        {
            return places;
        }
        set
        {
            places = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Places");
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Model class I have Id, City and Country properties:

```
public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

My question is related to the loop inside the code-behind file: how to extact Id from the row there so the application can know what row should be deleted?

```
foreach (var row in dgPlaces.SelectedItems)
{
    //here should be delete logic for each row
}
```

Why I can't just put . after row and than get Id from IntelliSense? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGrid.SelectedItems` property is non-generic, it is `IList` only, `row` has `object` type, unless exact type is specified like this:

```
foreach (Place row in dgPlaces.SelectedItems)
{

}
```